# Wake on HDMI monitor

Tags: display, debian

I am trying to get my Debian laptop to wake up when the monitor it is connected to via HDMI turns on. I have tried looking at xrandr but even when the tv is off at the plug it still shows it as being connected. I think windows can detect when a monitor is turned off using "monitor off detection"

Answer (score 0):

I believe that functionality is in the HDMI 1.3 spec.  Both your monitor and graphics card would have to be 1.3 compliant.